# SQL Find Active Cost Based on Order Date

Tags: sql, oracle

My company uses standard costing, and I'm wondering the best way to find the cost associated with an item at the time it was ordered? I'm using SQL to extract data (not putting data in tables).

For example, I have these costs for item ABC:

```
 Update Date      Cost
 12/26/2017       $40
 2/1/2017         $43
 12/27/2016       $39
```

In a different table, I have these orders for item ABC:

```
Order Date        Price
1/1/2018          $80
1/1/2017          $84
```

Here's how the data should be pulled together, but I'm not sure how:

```
Order Date        Price     Cost
1/1/2018          $80       $40
1/1/2017          $84       $39
```

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Add a cost column to the orders, insert cost on order when order is created. Don't try to retroactively calculate this.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select o.*,
       (select c.cost
        from costs c
        where c.updatedate <= o.orderdate
        order by c.updatedate desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as cost
from orders o;
```

This uses ANSI standard syntax.  Databases may differ on how they limit the result to one row.

EDIT:

In earlier versions of Oracle, there are multiple ways to approach this.  Here is one method:

```
select o.*,
       (select max(c.cost) keep (dense_rank first order by c.updatedate desc)
        from costs c
        where c.updatedate <= o.orderdate
       ) as cost
from orders o;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Very helpful. As written, it throws a Missing Right Parenthesis error prior to the Order By statement. Some research suggests it doesn't like the order statement because it's written to select a single line. Any ideas?

Comment: @ERKSMTY . . . Oracle supported `fetch first 1 row only` starting in Oracle 12.

Answer (score 0):

```
with costs (UpdateDate,Cost) as (
select to_date ('10/27/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy'),60 from dual union all
select to_date ('11/25/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy'),50 from dual union all
select to_date ('12/26/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy'),40 from dual union all
select to_date ('2/1/2017',   'mm/dd/yyyy'),43 from dual union all
select to_date ('11/27/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'),39 from dual union all
select to_date ('12/27/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'),35 from dual 
)
, orders (OrderDate,Price) as (
select to_date('1/1/2018','mm/dd/yyyy'),80 from dual union all
select to_date('1/1/2017','mm/dd/yyyy'),84 from dual
)
select orderdate, price, 
       max(updatedate) updt, 
       max(cost) keep(dense_rank first order by updatedate desc) cost
from (
  select * from orders join costs on (orders.orderdate >= costs.updatedate)
)
group by orderdate, price;
```